# Convert POST parameters to hash in Ruby without rails

Tags: ruby, http

What's the best library to use to convert the HTTP POST string received from a browser into a Ruby hash? I don't want to use the large rails-based libraries. I am using `eventmachine` and `evma_httpserver`, and want to include the lightest library possible that will decode and convert the params string.

Note: I don't need a webserver. I have the encoded post string in hand, and just need to convert it to a hash.

Comment: rack? http://rack.github.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`URI.decode_www_form` from the Ruby standard library can do this: http://rubydoc.info/docs/ruby-stdlib/1.9.2/URI#decode_www_form-class_method

Comment: Since writing this I've actually found a bug in URI.decode_www_form: With the right query string you can trigger an, ostensibly, infinite loop: `URI.decode_www_form('a=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&b')`. It seems like there's a really badly written regexp in there that will backtrack an exponential number of times (try decreasing the number of A's in the example, eventually you will get an answer).

Comment: Looks like ^^^ is no longer an issue?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`rack`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) gem for its [`Rack::Utils.parse_query`](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Utils.html) method.

If you want lighter than that, you could just copy the source code to the [`parse_query`](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L37) and [`unescape`](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/utils.rb#L23) methods from it.

If you want event lighter (but perhaps not as performant or robust) than that, just implement your own split and lean on `CGI.unescape`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```ruby
require "uri"    
result = URI.decode_www_form("your=post&params=values").inject({}) {|r, (key,value)| r[key.to_sym] = value;r}

puts result[:your]
puts result[:params]
```